# What is decent way in using a converter?

Tags: jsf-2, converters

For example I have 3 related tables and I have selectonemenus in different pages that are populated by these tables. To populate selectonemenus with objects I need converters. When writing a converter what is the decent way that takes memory consumption into account? I mean what values should definitely be in converter?

Answer (score 1):

> *I mean what values should definitely be in converter?*

Nothing. The converter should by itself not hold any state (expect of the injected entity service/DAO of course).

The `getAsString()` must just directly return the unique identifier of the entity which is supposed to be already known by the entity itself. I.e. it's a property of the entity itself which can be uniquely represented as `String`.

```
@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    Entity entity = (Entity) value;
    return entity.getId() != null ? String.valueOf(entity.getId()) : null;
}
```

The `getAsObject()` must just return the entity which is associated by its unique identifier. This is usually done by getting it from the service/DAO layer.

```
@Override
public String getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    Long id = Long.valueOf(value);
    return entityService.find(id);
}
```

An alternative to using the service/DAO in `getAsObject()` is to get it from `<f:selectItems>` so that any unnecessary DB calls can be avoided. See also [Avoid extra DB reads in the getAsObject method of converter class by caching data client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147119/avoid-extra-db-reads-in-the-getasobject-method-of-converter-class-by-caching-dat)

Comment: thanks for your clear answer. What about the other entities that this entity has relation? I can not reach the ID of the other entities if I don't set them in the converter of the first entity. Should I define the second entity's unique ID in the first entity's converter or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the concrete problem. What's the functional requirement?

Comment: Sorry for my unclear answer :) If I have 2 POJOs and in the converter of the first POJO, is it a must to add the unique ID of the second one? Can I avoid adding another field (the ID of the second class) to the converter of the first one? I hope I could explained..

Comment: Do you mean to say that the ID of the POJO depends on another POJO? Why this design?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I find another solution to this problem. But I still have problem in how to write a converter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444048/jsf-custom-converters