# JSF Custom Converters

Tags: jsf-2, converters

I have a custom converter like this:

```
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, String str) {
    System.out.println("vadeConverter before getAsObject(" + str);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");

    String values[] = str.split(":");
    Vade vade = new Vade();
    if (values.length > 1) {
        vade.setId(Integer.parseInt(values[0]));
        vade.setEtiket(values[1]);
        try{
            vade.setTakasTarihi(dateFormat.parse(values[2]));
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }
    System.out.println("vadeConverter after getAsObject(" + vade.toString());
    return vade;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        Object object) {
    Vade vade = (Vade) object;
    String str = "";
    System.out.println("vadeConverter before getAsString(object) -> " + vade.toString());
    if (vade != null) {
        str = vade.getId().toString()+":"+
                vade.getEtiket()+":"+
                vade.getTakasTarihi().toString()
                ;
    }
    System.out.println("vadeConverter after getAsString(object) -> " + str);
    return str;
}
```

In the output in the console is:

```
vadeConverter before getAsString(object) -> Vade{id=7etiket=T+0takasTarihi=2012-02-21}
vadeConverter after getAsString(object) -> 7:T+0:2012-02-21
vadeConverter before getAsString(object) -> Vade{id=12etiket=T+2takasTarihi=2012-02-27}
vadeConverter after getAsString(object) -> 12:T+2:2012-02-27
vadeConverter before getAsString(object) -> Vade{id=13etiket=T+3takasTarihi=2012-02-28}
vadeConverter after getAsString(object) -> 13:T+3:2012-02-28
vadeConverter before getAsString(object) -> Vade{id=14etiket=T+4takasTarihi=2012-02-29}
vadeConverter after getAsString(object) -> 14:T+4:2012-02-29
vadeConverter before getAsString(object) -> Vade{id=15etiket=T+5takasTarihi=2012-03-01}
vadeConverter after getAsString(object) -> 15:T+5:2012-03-01
vadeConverter before getAsString(object) -> Vade{id=16etiket=T+6takasTarihi=2012-03-02}
vadeConverter after getAsString(object) -> 16:T+6:2012-03-02
vadeConverter before getAsString(object) -> Vade{id=17etiket=T+7takasTarihi=2012-03-03}
vadeConverter after getAsString(object) -> 17:T+7:2012-03-03
vadeConverter before getAsString(object) -> Vade{id=18etiket=T+8takasTarihi=2012-03-04}
vadeConverter after getAsString(object) -> 18:T+8:2012-03-04
vadeConverter before getAsString(object) -> Vade{id=19etiket=T+9takasTarihi=2012-03-05}
vadeConverter after getAsString(object) -> 19:T+9:2012-03-05
```

when I select a value from the selectonemenu in the console I get this:

```
vadeConverter before getAsObject(12:T+2:2012-02-27
vadeConverter after getAsObject(Vade{id=12etiket=T+2takasTarihi=Fri Jan 27 00:02:00 EET 2012}
```

and of course as a result I get validation error. I believe I write the converter in right way, but I don't know what is wrong with this code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `mm` instead of `MM` to denote months. The `mm` stands for minutes. Note that you're getting `Jan` instead of `Feb` and that you get 2 minutes instead of 0 minutes. You can find the formatting pattern syntax [in `SimpleDateFormat` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

More reliable would however be to use `getTime()` and `new Date(time)` instead of `toString()` and `SimpleDateFormat#parse()`. This way you're also not dependent on the default `toString()` result.

Comment: right! thanks a lot! sometimes small mistakes costs you a lot.

Comment: I am good at learning through books. Is there any book that you can recommend which is essential for JSF?