# jsf - Reselecting data from DB in selectOneMenu placed in datatable inside dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

First of all, sorry for my English.
So, I'm working with jsf, using primefaces, and faced with the next problem:
I have a dialog with a datatable inside, datatable rows consist of row-selecting checkbox and selectOneMenu elements, and the first of selectOneMenu shows data from DB, using converter.

Page:

```
<h:form>
    <p:dialog>
        <p:panelGrid>
            <p:dataTable var="var", value="#{bean.enities}" rowKey=".." selection="#{bean.selection}">
                <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox"/>
                <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox"/>
                <p:ajax event="toggleSelect"/>
                <p:column style="text-align:center; width:20px;" selectionMode="multiple"/>
                <p:column>
                    <p:selectOneMenu  value="#{var.valueWithConverter}" converter="value1Converter" >
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="NULL" itemValue="#{null}"/>
                        <f:selectItems value="..." var="..." itemValue="..."  itemLabel="...}"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </p:column>
                <p:column >
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{valueWithoutConverter}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{...}"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:panelGrid>
     </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

Problem is that when i select some rows in row-selecting checkboxes column, for each selected row called getEntityById method in coverter class, which(method) calls select operation from DB. I'm using converter, that extends from javax.faces.covert.Converter.
Any ideas, what should I do to stop calling getEntityById method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Avoid extra DB reads in the getAsObject method of converter class by caching data client side?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147119/avoid-extra-db-reads-in-the-getasobject-method-of-converter-class-by-caching-dat)

Comment: @EmilKaminski Thanks for idea, but you suggest solution, how to avoid extra DB reads im getAsObject method, but I'm looking for **how to avoid calling getAsObject method**. I'm looking exactly for this solution, cause I have a working page, when the same construction (datatable with selectOneMenu) not in dialog not calls getAsObject method when i selecting row